# Cast id to objective-c defined protocol in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a framework written in Objective-C. One of the public method returns an id.
In Objective-C, I use force-cast to typecast the id value to a protocol so that I can invoke methods defined in the protocol. But when I want to use this framework in Swift, I don't know how to convert this id to a protocol.

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject
+ (id)generateProxyFromXML:(NSString*)xml protocol:(Protocol*)protocol;
@end
```

In Objective-C, I use the following codes:

```
@protocol AProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)doSomething;
@end

id<AProtocol> proxy = [MyManager generateProxyFromXML:@"" protocol:@protocol(AProtocol)];
[proxy doSomething];
```

But in Swift 3.0, I imported all headers:

```
let proxy = MyManager.generateProxyFromXML("", protocol: Protocol!(AProtocol))
```

How can I transfer this proxy to a protocol and invoke the method.

```
let proxy = MyManager.generateProxyFromXML("", protocol: Protocol!(AProtocol)) as! AProtocol
```

generates "Could not cast ..." runtime error.

**More Information**

In XML, I defined my database operations. And I pass XML and protocol to MyManager to generate a DAO proxy.

In MyManager, I use 'objc_allocateClassPair' to create a proxy class dynamically with name 'DAOProxy_#protocol_name#'. And then use 'protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList' to find the methods list of the protocol. And add these methods to the new class using 'class_addMethod'.

Finally I use the class 'DAOProxy_#protocol_name#' to create an instance and returns as 'id'. So that I can use this proxy instance to do database operations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at the moment, but try:

```
let proxy: protocol<AProtocol> = MyManager.generateProxyFromXML("")
```

or

```
let proxy = MyManager.generateProxyFromXML("") as! protocol<AProtocol>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried replace the protocol with AnyObject and it is OK. I can also invoke the method successfully. But with AnyObject it is not perfect .